# How to extract and transfer learnt parameters in svm(scikit)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I have trained SVM image classifier using sklearn. Assignment requirement is to make separate "prediction.py" function which takes an image and classifies it. Generally it's done by clf.predict() but how can I get values of learnt coefficients so that I may transfer them to predict.py function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scikit learn documentation addresses this, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html